# "Сладости" или "сласти"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильнее: "сладости" или "сласти"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то, верны оба варианта. Но по отношению к продуктам питания чаще употребляется слово "сладости", а "сласти" считается более просторченым.

Answer (score 1):

Грамотность - понятие относительное, не стоит забывать, что язык развивается и грамотное с безграмотным вполне могут поменяться местами.

Грамотность - это умение чувствовать не только статику, но и динамику языка. Сейчас в словарях отмечается равноправие вариантов "сладости - сласти" для обозначения кондитерских изделий. В дальнейшем весьма вероятно, что "сласти"  могут стать устаревшим словом, так как язык сочтет его лишним.

И по поводу "Д" в основе слова. Здесь и.-е. корень sal с расширителем d (соленый и сладкий - однокоренные слова, сравнить salt (англ.) - соль). Обе основы одновременно существовали еще в др.-рус. языке (сладость и сласть), образуя однокоренные слова "сладкий, сладостный" и "сластить, сластена".

Поэтому грамотность - это не только точное соответствие нашей речи современному словарю, но и знание истории языка и понимание всего процесса развития. Надо не просто заучивать норму произношения для конкретного слова, но и быть внимательным к  речевым особенностям. Возможно, перед нами действительно безграмотное наречие, а может быть, это более прогрессивный вариант, за которым будущее.

Answer (score 0):

Именно - сласти, а вот сладость - поцелуя, июльской ночи, аромата и т.п. Не хочу вдаваться в подробности, но то, что предлагает современная так называемая норма, мягко говоря, безграмотно. Тем более, что эту самую норму нынче описывают и закрепляют без учета всех составляющих нормы языка, а лишь с точки зрения  распространенности, что является огромной ошибкой и наносит серьезный ущерб культуре русского языка. Правда, помогает получить очередные деньги на внесение изменений в словари. Стыдно.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о собирательном названии сладких изделий, оба варианта вполне правильны.
"Сласти" - более старый, вытесняется современным "сладости".
При этом надо иметь в виду, что сласти - это только конфеты, мёд, кондитерские изделия и т.д., а "сладость" имеет еще несколько значений.

*Чуковский жил в эпоху, когда много чего было по-другому.*

Answer (score 0):

Кондитерские изделия, сладкое- Сласти. Проверочное слово - сластёна.
У восточных красавиц сладости. Проверочное слово - сладострастец.

Comment: А что проверяет "всласть"? ВСЛАСТЬ, нареч. Разг.
До полного удовлетворения; с наслаждением, с удовольствием. Наговориться в. Выспаться в. Налюбоваться в.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что в современное время говорить "сласти" по отношению к чему-либо съестному безграмотно. Т.к. совершенно не понятно, что значит корень слова. Но "сластёна" вполне м.б. введено в обиход как исключение (наравне с "сластить", "подсластить"), т.к. образовано от устаревшего "сласти". И уж тем более не м.б. использовано как проверочное слово. Проверочное слово м.б. использовано "сладкое", как определяющее вкус и суть контекста. Буква "д" является определяющей и не может выпадать, т.к. смысл существительного в получении удовольствия от слаДкого. Ответом на вопрос: "-А что у нас сегодня на сладкое?" - "Сласти", звучит как-то неадекватно. Слово "сласти" без указания ударения м.б. не верно истолковано и принято за указание к действию.

Comment: По поводу проверки это шутка. Новогодняя. Проверялся не буквенный состав корня, а область значений. Думаю, что различие в смысле и стиле хорошо видно по словарям. СЛАСТЬ, I. То же, что сладость (в 3 знач.). Накупить сластей. 2. перен. Что-н. очень приятное, хорошее (прост.). Какая с. искупаться в жару! Что за с. сидеть дома? Нагулялись в полную с. СЛАДОСТЬ 1. см. сладкий. 2. Сладкий вкус (разг.). В пироге мало сладости. 3. мн. Кондитерские изделия. Восточные сладости.

Answer (score 0):

Русскому  языку  меня  учили  люди,  которые  закончили  классические  гимназии,  Просто  режет  слух,  когда  слышишь: восточные  сладости,  вместо - восточные  сласти:  туфель,  тапочек,  пять  килограм,  вместо  - туфля, тапочка,   пять  килограммов.  Особенно  с  экрана,  люди  приучаются  говорить  по-русски  безграмотно.